# Most efficient way to remove elements from vector, do a calculation and put them back in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to find the best way to do a `cut` in a `vector` using 12 breaks, but I want the first cluster to contain values from 0 to a specific value (`onePercentQuantile`). So one way to do that is to remove all values below `onePercentQuantile` in `vector` while keeping track of the removed value indexes, then run a `cut` on `vector` with only 11 breaks and finally put back the removed indexes as cluster 1 in the new object, starting form the leftmost index.

I did not find a way to ignore values under a specific threshold in `cut` function, so I did it myself.
Here is an example with the most efficient way I could find :

```
vector_gene <- sample(1:100, 10000, replace=TRUE)
onePercentQuantile<- 5
indexUnderPercentQuantile <- which(vector_gene <= onePercentQuantile)
overPercentQuantile <- vector_gene[vector_gene > onePercentQuantile]

tmp <- as.numeric(cut(c(t(overPercentQuantile)),breaks=11))+1

if (1 == indexUnderPercentQuantile[1]){
  tmp <- insert(tmp, 1, values=1)
  indexUnderPercentQuantile <- indexUnderPercentQuantile[2:length(indexUnderPercentQuantile)]
}

for (i in 1:length(vector_gene)){
  if (i>length(tmp)){
    tmp <- c(tmp,rep(1,length(vector_gene)-i+1))
    break
  }
  else if (i == indexUnderPercentQuantile[1]){
    tmp <- c(tmp[1:i-1],1,tmp[i:length(tmp)])
    if (length(indexUnderPercentQuantile)>1){
      indexUnderPercentQuantile <- indexUnderPercentQuantile[2:length(indexUnderPercentQuantile)]
    }
  }
}
```

Using the `profvis` package I have traced memory usage and running time.

Up to 10.000 elements, result is instantaneous using barely no memory.

Up to 100.000 elements, memory usage is already around 9Go running in 3.5s

Up to 1.000.000 elements, the running time is so long that I shut it down.

The bottleneck is the reattribution of the removed indexes :

```
tmp <- c(tmp[1:i-1],1,tmp[i:length(tmp)])
```

I've tried the `insert` function in `R.utils` but it was worst in memory usage and running time

Is there a better way, especially in memory usage, to achieve this problem ? Thanks !

Comment: Why can't you do something like `cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf, seq(onePercentQuantile, max(x) + .Machine$double.eps, length.out = 11)))`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Roland,
The results I got are slightly different. I think `cut` function is taking the full `x` object to cut which I do not want to, I want the breaks calculation to be done on `x` minus values under the `onePercentQuantile`

Comment: I don't understand the difference. Why can't you cut the full object (while having the `onePercentQuantile` as a break)?

Comment: I think that's because `seq` and `cut` do not round breaks the same way :
`When breaks is specified as a single number, the range of the data is divided into breaks pieces of equal length, and then the outer limits are moved away by 0.1% of the range to ensure that the extreme values both fall within the break intervals`


I also think that `length.out` should be `12` to get 12 intervals


What is `.Machine$double.eps` useful for ?

Comment: I haven't tried the code. It might well have to be 12. My point is: If you want to do this efficiently, simply calculate the breaks you desire and then use `cut`. (I added `.Machine$double.eps` to try and ensure that the maximum falls within the interval. You can of course add 0.1 % of the range instead.)